# SQL average between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, average

I got two tables that are connected by `Computer_ID`.

First one is `Computer_ID`, `Country` which contains computers and their origin country and the second table contains information about the CPU: `Computer_ID`, `CPU_Manufacture`

I want to get, for each country, the average number of CPUs for a computer

I expect a result like this:

```
Country      |Avg CPUs
United-States|2.5
Canada       |3.2
```

Example data from `Computers` table:

```
Computer_ID|Country
1          |United-States
2          |United-States
3          |United-States
4          |United-States
5          |United-States
6          |Canada
7          |Canada
```

Example data from `CPU` table:
**Please notice that each computer can have multiple CPUs**

```
Computer_ID|CPU_Manufacture
1          |Intel
1          |Intel
2          |Intel
2          |AMD
2          |AMD
3          |AMD
4          |AMD
4          |Intel
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you showed us sample data from the two tables.  Can you do that?

Comment: Ofc! Sorry! Edited.

Comment: Should the result show only statistics for Intel cores?

Comment: It doesnt really matter

Answer (score 0):

My first question is: Why you have those 2 tables, when you could have that info in only one?
From what I gather, you want  a query like this:

```
select Country, Avg(Cores)
from computes as t1 left join cpu as t2
on (t1.computer_id = t2.computer_id)
where t2.CPU_Manufacture = 'Intel'
group by Country;
```

Comment: You should use a `LEFT JOIN` in case a certain country produce no Intel products.

Comment: yes, it's a bit different, but the query stills gives you the expected results. Have you even tried the query?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt work because I removed the "Cores" column.

Comment: I will post a new question

Comment: Agree. It's better you post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` your two tables and use the `AVG` function.

```
SELECT com.Country, AVG(cpu.cores) AS "Avg Cores"
FROM computers com
INNER JOIN cpu on com.Computer_ID = cpu.Computer_ID
```

Comment: and you are calculating your avg how?

Comment: If Mexico got 10 computers and those 10 computers got total of 20 cores the avg is then 2 for Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t.country,
  t.country_cpu_count / t.country_comp_count AS avg_cpus
FROM
(
  SELECT
    comp.country,
    count(distinct cpu.computer_id) over(partition by comp.country) AS country_comp_count
    count(cpu.cpu_manufacture)      over(partition by comp.country) AS country_cpu_count,
  FROM
    computers comp
  LEFT JOIN
    cpu cpu ON (cpu.computer_id = comp.computer_id)
) t
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it using this solution:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Country,[Computers]=COUNT(*) FROM Computers com
    GROUP BY Country
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Country,Cores=COUNT(*) FROM Computers com
    JOIN CPU cpu ON com.Computer_ID=cpu.Computer_ID
    GROUP BY Country
)
SELECT cte.Country,[Cores per computer]=ISNULL(Cores,0)*1./Computers
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte.Country=cte2.Country
```

You didn't specify how to treat countries without cores, so I represent them with 0 cores per computer.